# Play Framework Async Database Operation

Tags: hibernate, playframework-2.0, akka

I have Play 2 project with Hibernate as ORM and now I'm trying to perform a database operation asynchronous with the Akka-Helper:

```
Akka.future(
  new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() {
        Logger.info("Async called")
        Notification.newNotification(NotificationType.NEW_REQUEST, group.id, sender);
        return null;
    }
   }
);
```

The method call() is called but the database operation is not execuded. There is no error, is just happens nothing. 
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please post full code with play handlers, not just Akka call

Comment: What do you mean exactly? This snippet is like this in a Model method.